# show that a transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

show that the given transformation is linear:
$$T((1,0)) = (1,2,0)$$
$$T((0,1)) = (1,0,-1)$$ 
I know how to generally show a transformation is linear. But i am not sure how to do it if the transformation is given like that.

Comment: Well, you haven't yet *defined* a transformation on a vector space - you've only specified two points. This is like asking "if $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, show $f$ is a straight line."

Comment: Are you sure the tasks is to show it's linear? Because you can't do this, given only *this* information. Might the task be to find *the* linear map which satisfies these two conditions?

Comment: $((x+y), x^2, -y)$ is one example of a nonlinear transformation that satisfies the given equalities.

Comment: okei thanks. it did seem impossible. must be a error. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have to find the linear transformation which gives these results.

So we have $ T(e_1) = (1,2,0)$ and $T(e_2) = (1,0,-1)$.  Since the inputs form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ then the transform is

$$T = \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \>.$$

Can you see why this is the linear transform?